# Jenkins - Proxy authentication by certificate

Tags: jenkins, proxy, jks, zscaler

I am new to Jenkins.

My windows server installation has a Zscaler root certificate for authentication at the proxy in order  access internet.

Now I am trying to authenticate the jenkins at the Zscaler proxy with this certificate. The windows installed root certificate is not found by jenkins automatically.

Does anybody know how include a java keystore witht the certificate in the jenkins, so that the jenkins server can bypass the proxy and access internet with this certificate

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it via:

(1) Creating a java key store with keytool in java bin folder:

```
keytool -importcert -alias jenkins -keystore myKeyStore -storepass myPassword -file ca.der
```

In my case it was a cert ca certificate being renamed to pem.

(2) Afterwards I added the keystore to jenkins.xml inside the arguments field:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=somewhereInMyFilesystem/myKeystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=myPassword
```

(3) Restart